# Beam Pub/Sub pipeline window group by value

Tags: apache-beam

I have setup a basic playground beam pipeline that uses a fixed window on incoming sensor data via a pub/sub topic.

Code:

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

pipeline
    .apply("Read PubSub Messages", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowSize()))))
    .apply("Write Files to GCS", new WriteOneFilePerWindow(options.getOutput(), numShards));
```

My incoming data, that is stored on the bucket has this layout.

```
{"deviceId":"e97c6cce-5341-429b-a49d-506e9af1c845","value":79206.34,"sensorId":"b1185c92-4f07-4ef0-86ee-2fe38bdaaf33","timeInNanoSeconds":1671485053899000000,"receivedTimeInNanoSeconds":16714850539867940
{"deviceId":"d2fa82a7-d70e-4057-8d4f-769c21815195","value":28.83,"sensorId":"8a308426-bfc7-417b-a278-ae9c6353f080","timeInNanoSeconds":1671485065774000000,"receivedTimeInNanoSeconds":1671485065796548000}
```

I need to group the window on the sensorId - means there should be a fixed window for each sensorId. In the end, I want to persist a window per sensor.

From what I understand in the docs, I should go with **GroupByKey**

Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, you would want to use a [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/groupbykey/) here. To use a GroupByKey, you need to transform your data into `KV`s. E.g.

```
pipeline
    .apply("Read PubSub Messages", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowSize()))))
    .apply(ParDo
      .of(new DoFn<String, KV<String, String>>() {
          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String json = c.element();
            [parse the json to get deviceId out]
            c.output(KV.of(deviceId, json));
          }
      }))
    .apply(GroupByKey.of()) // Groups by key and window.
    .apply(ParDo
      .of(new DoFn<KV<String, Itarable<String>>, String>() {
          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            KV<String, Itarable<String>> grouped = c.element();
            String deviceId = grouped.key();
            Iterable<String> messages = grouped.value();
            [loop over your messages to compute the result]
            c.output(result);
          }
      }))
...
```